# Variable not declared until set in preferences

Tags: android, global-variables, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an app that works with database and offers option to create backup on external storage. App gets the backup directory from preferences, but since it's not set when I run app for the first time, I use a default path instead, simply by getting path to external storage and creating a directory there.

For all this, I use global string value which keeps the backup path. But here's my problem - when I run my app for the first time, I declare the default path in `onCreate()` method. When I try to write this path to log, it works. But then I have `onClick()` method, where I listen to click on button, which calls dialog with export/import options. When I try to write the backup path to log from here, the string is empty.

Variable itself shouldn't be the issue, because here's the interesting thing - when I go to preferences and set the backup path from there (which is then saved to string variable just the same way as it was before), I can suddenly get the variable from the `onClick` method and everything works fine.

Just for the record, I tried setting different path and I've always been choosing same path in preferences as I used manually in the `onCreate` method.

Any ideas what could be the issue? I can write the whole condition for backup path used in `onCreate` also into the `onClick` method and that would probably solve this issue, but I would like to avoid duplicite code and it's also really bugging me.

**EDIT:**

Here's code of the condition I use in the `onCreate` method.

```
location = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(location.getString("backup_location", "").equals("")) {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/simpledbmanager_backup");

        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        this.backup = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
    }
}
else {
    this.backup = location.getString("backup_location", "");
}
```

Comment: So when you run program for first time, onClick does not return string set in oncreate, but returns correct sharepreference? The second part seems normal, first part may be because of a bug. You should post your code so people can help.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted it, I've added the code just now. And you're correct.